# Find path from where .exe is run Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a compiled ahk script in which I use %_A_WorkingDir% to get the current working directory. But now I'm calling the .exe from another file two folders up so %_A_WorkingDir% returns the directory that is two folders up, not the location of the actual .exe. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

- **A_WorkingDir** is the directory in which the script is currently
  working. You can change it by using
  the command *SetWorkingDir*.
- **A_ScriptDir** is the full path of the directory where the script is in.
- **A_ScriptFullPath** is the full path of the current script.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#prop